# How do I find the range? Details below

Tags: quantiles, z-score, range

"The average mark in a grade 9 math class is 75.5% with a standard deviation of 9.5%. If Grade 9 math marks have a normal distribution:

b) Within what range of marks are 99.7% of all students?"

In a normal distribution curve, 99.7 percentile is a z-score of 2.75. How would I find the range of marks in this instance? Would I use the z-score formula?

Comment: Yes, use the z-score formula.

Comment: Also, 99.7 should be a z-score of 3.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=68-95-99.7

Comment: consider adding the tag `[self-study]`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oswego.edu/~srp/stats/6895997.htm

This may be of interest to you.

The range would be about (75.5 - 3*9.5, 75.5 + 3*9.5), but not exactly as normalcdf(-3,3) = 99.73. To get a bit more accurate you'd have to find the area of the end tips you don't want, (1-99.7)/2, and invNorm that. Would be like 2.999984, so 3 is probably good enough.

The z-score of 2.75 is referring to a graph starting at the far left up to 2.75 standard deviations, which is not what you want in this question.